# .Net server backend - step into breakpoints when debugged on localhost

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, backend

I have a .Net backend. I'm able to debug it online with attaching a debugger. Now I want to run it locally - which is ok (the "is up and running" - page shows in Firefox), but it doesn't stop at breakpoints.

Is there a trick to do that?

**Solution (in my case):**

Restart Visual Studio

Comment: please describe the '.Net backend'. What type of project is it, how are you running this etc. etc.

Comment: It's an azure app project. Normally it's published and then runs on a azure server... Found the solution.. I had simply to restart the project...